# Trying to determine if the answer key in the open source calculus volume 1 book by OpenStax is incorrect in regards to a specific problem

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Image 1 is the textbook question and image 2 is the graph in question.

[image]

[image]

The answer key says that the domain is all real numbers. I thought that the domain is actually -2<x<2.

My question is, is the answer key incorrect in this case or am I wrong? I'm new to learning math as a hobby and I don't have anyone who can help me with math in life, hence why i'm here. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are those images?

Comment: When I click edit, the links appear in the text but for some reason it doesn't appear when I click save edits.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y9XE.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZV8Z.jpg

Comment: The instructions in the question ask you to assume that the graph extends beyond the image.  It is hard to know exactly what the authors mean by this, but you are clearly supposed to think about what happens beyond the frame.  That said, I think that the question is fundamentally unanswerable, as you could make all kinds of arguments about *how* the function continues.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the images aren't showing up. They're completely relevant to the question. This is my first post here so I don't know why it's not working. I copied and pasted the images directly into the box when creating this question and it automatically converted into an imgur link because I apparently need points to post the images directly. But the links don't seem to appear within the question unless I click edit where it all there amongst the rest of the text.

Comment: When you edit, look below the edit window. The results of your edits will be shown there. Links to images are handled in a way that is not obvious from the text in the edit window. I made the images visible and you removed them. I will revert your edit; please look at the preview below the edit window before submitting your next edit.

Comment: Is this "MathStax" something we can view online? Can you provide a link to the page where this problem appears? As noted in a comment above, if we look only at the two images you provlded, there's not enough information to answer the question. It's possible that the missing information is on some part of the page you didn't copy, and it's possible that the information is really missing.

Comment: @DavidK MathStax is part of the OpenStax OER (open educational resources) project.  Since it is an OER, I would imagine that the text this comes from should be freely available.  However, there are several books in the MathStax part of the project, so a tighter reference would be required.

Comment: It's from an opensource textbook from Openstax (not Mathstax, my bad). But it wouldn't help here since all the information that I cropped from it is 100% of what's relating to the question. This is just from the beginning of the book so probably only high school level.

Comment: Found it. https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/1-1-review-of-functions It's in Section 1.1 Exercises, near the bottom of the page, and there really isn't any extra information.

Comment: @Dave  It is my opinion that this isn't a very good question for demonstrating the phenomena that it is trying to demonstrate.  To someone with a fair bit of experience, this function "looks like" a polynomial, and someone with experience knows how a polynomial behaves:  they are defined everywhere (i.e. the domain of a polynomial is $\mathbb{R}$), and they grow infinitely large (either in the negative direction, the positive direction, or both).  But from that picture alone, there isn't any way of knowing.  If I were grading your work, I'd have given you the points.

Comment: But the problem is, at the end of the day, a bit of a mind reading exercise.  I don't think that it is useful to spend too much time worrying about it.

Comment: I see, thank you all very much for your help. This seems like a great community and I am looking forward to spending more time becoming a part of it.